# Trouble getting a SubImage of an Image in Go

Tags: go

I'm doing some image processing in Go, and I'm trying to get the SubImage of an Image.

```
import (
  "image/jpeg"
  "os"
)
func main(){
  image_file, err := os.Open("somefile.jpeg")
  my_image, err := jpeg.Decode(image_file)
  my_sub_image := my_image.SubImage(Rect(j, i, j+x_width, i+y_width)).(*image.RGBA)
}
```

When I try to compile that, I get `.\img.go:8: picture.SubImage undefined (type image.Image has no field or method SubImage)`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You might want't to write more idiomatic Go code, e.g. naming variables like `imageFile` instead of `image_file` as this helps reviewing your code.

Answer (score 18):

Here is an alternative approach - use a type assertion to assert that `my_image` has a `SubImage` method.  This will work for any [image](http://golang.org/pkg/image) type which has the `SubImage` method (all of them except `Uniform` at a quick scan).  This will return another `Image` interface of some unspecified type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/jpeg"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    image_file, err := os.Open("somefile.jpeg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    my_image, err := jpeg.Decode(image_file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    my_sub_image := my_image.(interface {
        SubImage(r image.Rectangle) image.Image
    }).SubImage(image.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10))

    fmt.Printf("bounds %v\n", my_sub_image.Bounds())

}
```

If you wanted to do this a lot then you would create a new type with the `SubImage` interface and use that.

```
type SubImager interface {
    SubImage(r image.Rectangle) image.Image
}

my_sub_image := my_image.(SubImager).SubImage(image.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10))
```

The usual caveats with [type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) apply - use the `,ok` form if you don't want a panic.

Answer (score 8):

Because `image.Image` doesn't have a method `SubImage`. You need to use a type assertion to get the appropriate `image.*` type.

```
rgbImg := img.(image.RGBA)
subImg := rgbImg.SubImage(...)
```